# Isn't there any student of the same height as Tom in the class if "Tom is the tallest in the class"?

Tags: superlatives

If Jim is the same height as Tom, and other students in their class are not as tall as them, then can we say

> Tom is the tallest student in his class.

? Or, Should I say

> Tom is a tallest student in his class.

? Or, Should I say

> Tom and Jim are the tallest students in his class.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Superlative implies one**.

Comparative deals with equivalents. (Jim is as tall as Tom.)

**With superlatives we always use "*THE*", which is singular**:

*THE* most or *THE* least, etc., one single entity of a group.  "Entity" can be the one object or the one group of objects.

"Tom is *THE* tallest."  There is no one taller or as tall as Tom.
If Jim is as tall as Tom, then Tom is not THE tallest.  Neither is Jim THE tallest.

"Tom and Jim are the tallest *ones* in the class."

Answer (score 3):

You can say

> Tom is one of the tallest students in his class.

or

> Tom and Jim are the tallest students in their class.

Saying that

> Tom is the tallest student in his class

does somewhat mean that there is no one of the same height.

But you cannot say that

> Tom is *a* tallest student in his class.

Comment: I disagree that saying *Tom is the tallest...* is correct if there is another of exactly the same height. One could indeed say *one of the two tallest....* But superlatives are superlatives and I do not believe they allow for other exact equivalents. Apart from anything else it involves the definite article, which indicates singularity.

Comment: @WS2 'Tom and Jim are the tallest.' The superlative may be applied to a subset of order greater than one.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree.

Comment: Wish I could vote twice

Comment: Or "Jim's class". But to be impartial with respect to both Tom and Jim, let's say "their" :-)